# using JQuery functions on a string of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string of html, on which i want to use jquery functions.
The string has `divs` as below.

```
var html=        
    <div class = foo>
    some code
    <div class = bar>

    //more divs, code

    </div>
    </div>
```

I need to select the `divs` with `class` 'bar' out of these and use it for something. This is what I'm doing

```
var jqueryObj = jQuery( html);
jQuery('.bar', jqueryObj).wrap(   //a new div );
```

but this doesnt seem to be working. 
its not taking the context of `jqueryObj` correctly.
Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try `jQueryObj.find('.bar')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/LMZ4V/

It selects everything with a class of bar, and sets its html to `Test`, then prints the html to a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

if your format of `String` is always like the above snippet try this..

```
html.replace("<div class = bar>","<div class=newDiv><div class = bar>");
html+="</div>"
```

But, this isn't JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html= '<div class = foo>some code<div class = bar></div></div>';
var result = $(html);
result.find(".bar").wrap("<div/>")
console.log(result);
```